# Dupeblocker on apex data loader

Tags: dupeblocker

I uploaded accounts in my org using data loader, batch size set to 2000.
In the file I loaded, there are few duplicates which our dupeblocker will create warning on but allows you to create records.

But when I ran the data loader, i didn't see any warning created but I know there are duplicates.

I re uploaded the file with batch size set to 1, now I see all warning created as expected.

Do dupeblocker recognize the data loader? will it work only for 1 record at a time?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Salesforce Duplicate Management or the 3rd-party application DupeBlocker? If the latter, you may wish to reach out to the vendor directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're using Bulk API in the data loader settings. Because the Bulk API loads records in parallel (asynchronously), there is a high chance that duplicates are missed. Try checking

> Enable Serial Mode for Bulk API

This should hopefully catch all duplicates but from what I recall it processes in batches of 200. You can read this artice for more details - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/The_Salesforce_Bulk_API_-_Maximizing_Parallelism_and_Throughput_Performance_When_Integrating_or_Loading_Large_Data_Volumes

Comment: Thanks @jitender, I tried enabling serial mode for Bulk API still didn't work

Comment: I guess it might be good to reach out to the vendor then, because the code needs to handle the possibility of duplicates in the current batch of 200 as well. Hopefully they can let you know if they took that into consideration while writing their code.